# How do I permanently remove an application from Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts, slack

Our team was trying out Slack for a month and I added the Slack app to Google Hangouts, apparently. Now when I enter a hangout I see this sidebar:

[image: Slack sidebar]

Since I stopped using Slack, I've tried removing the app with this button on the right sidebar:

[image: Yes, remove Slack!]

And I get this prompt:

[image: The cake is a lie.]

But the next time I start up a Hangout, the sidebar is back. I found Google's [Add or remove an app in Hangouts](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2539435?hl=en), but it doesn't actually say how to remove apps. We are using [Google Apps for Work](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/). Do I need to contact an SA to fix this or can I do it on my own?

(Note to developers: can we agree to stop overloading the term "app" now?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete the following steps to completely remove the Slack/Hangouts integration.

1. Go to your Slack URL for service integrations:
   https://.slack.com/services
2. Under Google+ Hangouts click the hyperlinked "• Easy creation of..."
3. On the left side click "Remove Integration"
4. Click OK on the popup
5. Close Slack
6. Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions
7. Revoke Slack's permissions to access Hangouts

*Note: Each Slack/Google user that setup and authorized the integration will need to complete these steps.*

Comment: Yep. That did the trick. Out of curiosity, would steps 6 & 7 be sufficient?

Comment: @JonEricson Glad to hear! Yes, completing only steps 6 and 7 would do it. Slack would still show the Hangouts as an active option on their end, but it doesn't matter if you are no longer using it.